# Upgrade from SQL Server RC

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I was using SQL Server 2016 RC3. I knew it has a 180 day life on it. Now that the full version is out, I would like to upgrade.

How do you do that? I want to upgrade my current version, as opposed to creating a new instance, or even a new server (there can only be one default instance) and moving it all over.

Comment: First answer from google; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677622.aspx

Answer (score 2):

When you launch the new install, instead of selecting 'New SQL Server...' there is an option to upgrade an existing installation.  It does not list 2016RC but it will work.  You will be able to select the instance to upgrade.